# Find a formula in $n, a, m, d$ for the sum: $(a+md)+(a+(m+1)d+(a+(m+2)d)+ ...+ (a+(m+n)d$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

where m and n are integers, $n$ greater than or equal to $0$ and $a$ and $d$ are real numbers. Justify your result.

By distributing and factoring, I have gotten up to $(a+md)n+d(1+...+n)$ but I am stuck on what to do next.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Change your variables!

Set $A:= a+md$ , $D:=d$ and $N:=n$. Your sequence turns out to be

$A,A+D,A+2D,...,A+ND$.

Now what is the sum of an arithmetic progression?

Comment: I was able to look up the formula, but since I haven't learned it in class I would have to prove it if I want to use it. Is there another more intuitive way to do this?

Comment: @DebMartin There can't be another way to do this. Your question specifically asks to find the sum of a certain arithmetic progression. I did nothing but replacing the first arithmetic progression by a simpler one. In other words, if you want to solve the problem you have to find a way to calculate the sum of an arithmetic progression. There is no other way.